# How to add "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" when running container from kubernetes deployment yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm setting up a kubernetes deployment with an image that will execute docker commands (`docker ps` etc.).

My yaml looks as the following:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: discovery
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    discovery-app: kubernetes-discovery
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      discovery-app: kubernetes-discovery
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        discovery-app: kubernetes-discovery
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker:dind
        name: discover
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: my-awesome-port
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred3
      volumes:
      - name: some-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-discovery
```

Normally I will run a docker container as following:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker:dind`

Now, kubernetes yaml supports `commands` and `args` but for some reason does not support `options`.

What is the right thing to do?

Perhaps I should configure a volume, but then, is it volumeMount or just a volume?

I am new with kubernetes so it is important for me to do it the right way.

Thank you

Comment: In general in Kubernetes, only the per-host “kubelet” process should be interacting with the Docker daemon.  Your process can talk to the Kubernetes API if it needs to spawn other pods, but you don’t generally try to access the host’s Docker socket.

Comment: I am running a python script that runs the docker commands.
The script inspects all docker container images  in a given namespace, that means I run  (python equivalent to) ```docker inspect``` and ```docker pull```. For that reason I can not avoid connecting to the host docker daemon. 
I am assuming docker is installed on the host machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to add the volume to the container.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: discover
    image: docker:dind
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I had to remove `type: File` in the `volumes > hostPath` section. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bad idea to interact directly with containers on any nodes in Kubernetes. The whole point of Kubernetes is to orchestrate. If you add containers outside of the Pod construct, then Kubernetes will not be aware the processes running on the nodes. This will affect resource allocation.

It also needs to be said that directly working with containers bypasses security.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable for a CI/CD system to use containers in K8s that are building other containers.

Comment: Agreed that CI/CD is a use-case - I found this question while setting up Drone, which does exactly that.

Comment: To anyone here - Kubernetes has deprecated this functionality as of the date I write this.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum do you have a link to the documentation showing where this functionality was deprecated?

Comment: @OladapoAjala - Yes - https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/02/17/dockershim-faq/, and specifically on that page, https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/02/17/dockershim-faq/#is-there-any-tooling-that-can-help-me-find-dockershim-in-use