# “Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: DockerException Error while fetching server API version” while starting jupyterhub with DockerSpawner

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I started using jupyterhub, right now I am fighting with errors, and I hope you can help a little.
I have a working jupyterhub configuration:

```
import environ 
import simplespawner
import tmpauthenticator

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 2
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(str(ROOT_DIR.path(".env")))

c.JupyterHub.port = 8008
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = tmpauthenticator.TmpAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = simplespawner.SimpleLocalProcessSpawner
c.Spawner.notebook_dir = NOTEBOOK_DIR
```

and it’s ok, but right now I’d like to change SimpleLocalProcessSpawner to DockerSpawner. I ran

```
docker pull jupyterhub/singleuser
```

and changed above configuration into:

```
....
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = dockerspawner.DockerSpawner
c.DockerSpawner.image = 'jupyterhub/singleuser:latest'
docker0 = netifaces.ifaddresses('docker0')
docker0_ipv4 = docker0[netifaces.AF_INET][0]
c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = docker0_ipv4['addr']
```

Right now I end up with error:

> 500 : Internal Server Error Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start:
> DockerException Error while fetching server API version: (‘Connection
> aborted.’, PermissionError(13, ‘Permission denied’)) You can try
> restarting your server from the home page.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Writing:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

allows me to run jupyterhub in this configuration. Problem is I must run it after each restart of computer. How to make it permanent?

Comment: For who those are looking for a K8S solution for it, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462354/4469992) is gold:

Answer (score 0):

There could be several possible causes for this error:

1. Make sure the user that runs JupyterHub is a member of the `docker` group (check it with `id`). This is quite likely as by setting `/var/run/docker.sock`'s permissions to 666 fixes the problem.
2. The container must mount the Docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. If you have a `docker-compose.yml` file then it should contain the corresponding `volumes` setting like this:

   ```
    volumes:
        # Give access to Docker socket
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   ```
3. Something else... given the complexity of Docker and JupyterHub. :-)